# Retrain Tensorflow inception v3 network from Java

Tags: java, android, python, tensorflow

I have been able to retrain an image classifier in Tensorflow using inception v3 from python, and the use the model from Java (Android and JSE) to classify and image.

Is it possible to retrain from the inception v3 model entirely in Java, without using python? (Android, or JSE)

Answer (score 1):

I never tried it myself, but TensorFlow has APIs that can be used from [Java](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/java/reference/org/tensorflow/package-summary) and [Python](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/) (and a few others), so you should be able to achieve the same results with `Java` code. However, you may want to keep the training in `python` since the APIs for Java may be [unstable](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/):

> A word of caution: the APIs in languages other than Python are not yet covered by the API stability promises.

Also, since you want to use the model on mobile devices, I would suggest to have a look on [`MobileNet`](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/slim/nets/mobilenet_v1.md) which was designed for this task.

> MobileNets trade off between latency, size and accuracy while comparing favourably with popular models from the literature.

I worked with both and obtained decent results. As expected, `Inception` always had better results, but it took longer to train and evaluate and image.

Comment: Thanks. Looking into it more it does not look feasible to train Tensorflow in Java. Looks like you need to use python.